# How to sum fields of two lists conditionally

Tags: c#, .net

I need to sum X and Y fields of two lists, but where first Id equals to second Id.

My code:

```
//Program.cs

//(...)

class Point
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point(int _Id, int _X, int _Y)
    {
        Id = _Id;
        X = _X;
        Y = _Y;
    }
}

//(...)

List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
List<Point> sumsXY = new List<Point>();

//sum the X and Y of two lists, but points.Id must equal to sumsXY.Id
for (int i = 0; i < objcount; i++)
{
    sumsXY[points[i].Id].X = sumsXY[points[i].Id].X + points[i].X;
    sumsXY[points[i].Id].Y = sumsXY[points[i].Id].Y + points[i].Y;
}
```

Need help.

David

Comment: Do you have several points in second list which correspond to single point in first list?

Comment: @David If you set, `sumsXY[i].Id = i` for each `i`. Your code works, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var sumsXY = points.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                   .Select(g => new Point(g.Key, g.Sum(x => x.X),
                                          g.Sum(x => x.Y)))
                   .ToList();
```

This groups all points with the same ID together and creates a new point for each group with the ID of that group and the sum of the X and Y values of all points in the group.

This answer assumes that `sumsXY` is empty at the beginning of this operation. If this is not the case, you might want to clarify your question and provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Don't know if this actually works, but the point is that OP *changes* one of the lists, which is not possible to achieve *only* with LINQ.

Comment: @Tigran: I am not so sure that this is the point. Please see the last paragraph of my answer for the assumptions it is based on.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Point> newList = new List<Point>();
foreach(Point p in points)
{
  Point sumsXYPoint = sumsXY.FirstOrDefault(sums => sums.Id == p.Id);
  if (sumsXYPoint != null)
  {
    newList.Add(new Point() { Id = p.Id, X = sumsXYPoint.X + p.X, Y = sumsXYPoint.Y + p.Y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work for you:

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
List<Point> sumsXY = new List<Point>();

points.Add(new Point(1, 10, 10));
points.Add(new Point(2, 10, 20));
points.Add(new Point(3, 10, 30));

sumsXY.Add(new Point(1, 100, 100));
sumsXY.Add(new Point(5, 10, 20));
sumsXY.Add(new Point(6, 10, 30));

foreach (Point p in points)
{
     foreach (Point s in sumsXY)
     {
         if (s.Id == p.Id)
         {
             s.X += p.X;
             s.Y += p.Y;
         }
     }
 }
```

Gives:

- 110 110
- 10 20
- 10 30